# Determine Facebook Login permissions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-login

I have FB login on my site (I use ASP.NET MVC), when user try to login he/she can uncheck email in permission section, this action causes problems for my side, because email is NULL and I need it to identify user.

Please give me advice how can I restrict to uncheck email permission ?
Thank you

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/handling-declined-permissions

Comment: Hop you are aware though that you won’t get an email from every Facebook user though - simply because for example a large part of those who registered using their mobile will likely not even have an email address on file with Facebook. So if your app absolutely needs one, you need to implement an additional step to let the user input it manually in such cases; of course verification is your responsibility as well then.

Comment: what is the best way to make login without any problems?